Continuous basis $(e_1(t),e_2(t))$
Assume that $t \mapsto A(t)$ is a $n \times n$ matrix-valued continuous function and that we know that $\ker A(t)$ has dimension $2$ for every real $t$.

Prove that there is are continuous vector-valued functions $e_1(t), e_2(t)$ such that these vectors form a basis of $\ker A(t)$ for all $t$.

I am able to prove local existence of such vectors $e_i(t)$ by using the Gauss elimination algorithm. So for every real $t_0$ I can find an interval $I_{t_0}$ that contains $t_0$ and continuous functions $t\mapsto e_i(t)$ and such that for all $t\in I_{t_0}$, $(e_1(t),e_2(t))$ is a basis of $\ker A(t)$.
How can I prove that such continuous parametrization can be extended globally in time?  Maybe it is just a simple trick to use but I don't see it.

This is a very concrete consequence of the nontrivial fact that a vector (or principal)  bundle on $\Bbb R$ (or any contractible paracompact space) is globally trivial. Partitions of unity are used. (Apply this to the pullback of the universal bundle on the Grassmannian $G(2,n)$.)

Sorry it's dimension 2 for the kernel.
@TedShifrin good way to see it, thank you!

Yes, Gaussian elimination gives local triviality, but then you need to glue on overlaps. This amounts to the proof that the Grassmannian is a manifold, and then local triviality of the frame bundle will do it. I don't see a totally elementary argument.

This can be proved with elementary linear algebra. Let us write $A_t$ for $A(t)$. Let $r$ be the constant rank of all $A_t$, where $0<r<n$. (In your case $r=n-2$.)
For any pair of matrices $M$ and $K$ we call $K$ a kernel matrix of $M$ if its columns form a basis of $\ker(M)$. In the present context, for any interval $U\subseteq\mathbb R$, we call $B:U\to M_{n,n-r}(\mathbb R)$ a kernel matrix function (of $A$) if $B_t$ is a kernel matrix of $A_t$ for every $t\in U$.
To construct a continuous kernel matrix function on $\mathbb R$, it suffices to show that given any $\tau\in\mathbb R$ and any kernel matrix $K$ of $A_\tau$, there is a continuous kernel matrix function $B$ on $[\tau-1,\tau]$ or $[\tau,\tau+1]$ such that $B_\tau=K$. Once this is done, we may start with a kernel matrix $K$ of $A_0$ and construct iteratively a continuous kernel matrix function on each of the intervals $[0,1],[1,2],\ldots$ and $[-1,0],[-2,-1],\ldots$, so that any two functions constructed on two adjacent intervals agree at the common endpoint. Then a continuous kernel matrix function on the whole real line is obtained by gluing them.
So, without loss of generality, assume that $\tau=0$ and we only need to construct a continuous kernel matrix function $B$ on $[0,1]$ with $B_0$ equals some prespecified kernel matrix $K$ of $A_0$.
Since $A_t$ has a constant rank $r$ on $[0,1]$, there exists, at any time $t$, an index set $\mathcal I(t)\subseteq\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ of cardinality $r$ such that the columns of the submatrix $A_t(:,\mathcal I(t))$ form a basis of the column space of $A_t$. As $A$ is a continuous function, there is also an open interval $U(t)\ni t$ such that the submatrix $A_s(:,\mathcal I(t))$ has full column rank for all $s\in U(t)$.
The collection $\{U(t):t\in[0,1]\}$ is an open cover of $[0,1]$. Hence we may retrieve from it a finite subcover $\{(a_i,b_i) : 0\le i\le k\}$. By a reindexing we may assume that $a_0\le a_1\le\ldots\le a_k$. By a judicial removal of intervals, we may also assume that no interval in this subcover is a subinterval of another. It follows that $a_{i-1}<a_i<b_{i-1}<b_i$ for each $i$.
We shall construct our continuous kernel matrix function $B$ on $[0,1]$ iteratively:

(Initialisation.) Construct $B$ on $[0,b_0)$ from a kernel matrix $K$ of $A_0$.
(Iteration.) For $i=1,2,\ldots,k$, extend the previously constructed $B$ on $[0,b_{i-1})$ to one on $[0,b_i)$.
(Finalisation.) Trim the domain of $B$ from $[0,b_k)$ to $[0,1]$.

In the first step, we need the following lemma, whose proof is easy and is omitted.

Lemma. Let $0<r<n$ and $M=\pmatrix{X&Y}\in M_n(\mathbb R)$ be a rank-$r$ matrix, where $X$ has $r$ linearly independent columns. A matrix $K$ is a kernel matrix of $M$ if and only if
$$
K=\pmatrix{-X^+YW\\ W}\text{ for some } W\in GL_{n-r}(\mathbb R).
$$
Similarly, if $\mathcal I$ is an index set of cardinality $r$ such that the columns of $M(:,\mathcal I)$ form a basis of the column space of $M$, and $\mathcal J$ is its complement in $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, then $K$ is a kernel matrix of $M$ if and only if
$$
\pmatrix{K(\mathcal I,:)\\ K(\mathcal J,:)}
=\pmatrix{-M(:,\mathcal I)^+M(:,\mathcal J)W\\ W}\text{ for some } W\in GL_{n-r}(\mathbb R).
$$

Recall that for each $i$, there is an index set $\mathcal I(t_i)$ such that the rank of $A_s(:,\mathcal I(t_i))$ is $r$ for all $s\in(a_i,b_i)$. Let us abuse the notation and write $\mathcal I_i$ for $\mathcal I(t_i)$. Let $\mathcal J_i$ be the complement of $\mathcal I_i$ in $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$. Now suppose that a kernel matrix $K$ of $A_0$ is given. By our lemma, we must have
$$
\pmatrix{K(\mathcal I_0,:)\\ K(\mathcal J_0,:)}
=\pmatrix{-A_0(:,\mathcal I_0)^+ A_0(:, \mathcal J_0) W_0\\ W_0}
$$
for some invertible matrix $W_0$. Since the rank of $A_s(:,\mathcal I_0)$ is also $r$ for all $s\in (a_0,b_0)$. By the lemma above, the function $B$  defined on $(a_0,b_0)$ by
$$
\pmatrix{\color{red}{B_s}(\mathcal I_0,:)\\ \color{red}{B_s}(\mathcal J_0,:)}
=\pmatrix{-A_{\color{red}{s}}(:,\mathcal I_0)^+ A_{\color{red}{s}}(:, \mathcal J_0) W_0\\ W_0}
$$
is a kernel matrix function, and obviously $B_0=K$. Moreover, as the Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse of a matrix $X$ of full column rank is $X^+=(X^TX)^{-1}X^T$, we see that $B$ is continuous on $(a_0,b_0)$. Now the initialisation step is completed by trimming the domain of $B$ from $(a_0,b_0)$ to $[0,b_0)$.
Next, in each iteration, suppose $B$ has been constructed on $[0,b_{i-1})$. Since $a_{i-1}<a_i<b_{i-1}<b_i$, there exists some positive $\tau\in(a_{i-1},b_{i-1})\cap(a_i,b_i)$. By a similar argument to the initialisation step, there is a continuous kernel matrix function $C$ on $[\tau,b_{i+1})$ such that $C_\tau=B_\tau$. A new continuous kernel matrix function $B$ on $[0,b_i)$ is then obtained by gluing the restriction of the old $B$ on $[0,\tau]$ and $C$ together. After $k$ iterations and the finalisation step, we are done.
